# Is it OK to correct new users on formatting?

Tags: discussion, new-users

I've noticed that a lot of `new users` tend to `format` their `posts` like this, where they put things they want to `emphasize` or things that are even just barely vaguely `technical` in `code blocks`. This drives me nuts.

Is it OK to tell the person in a comment that they're formatting wrong, similar how we do the "welcome to Stack Exchange, we like repeatable questions" (or whatever other problem) dance?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Don't harass. Just fix it, with a friendly comment in the edit summary.

Comment: +1 Except for chronic repeat offenders: then your edit summary can be a little more pointed...

Comment: This. It's what the "edit" link is for, after all.

Comment: I love the fact that the community actually edits each others posts. It makes sense to do so as it helps to show what the question actually is.

Comment: If I was the "new user" you were referring to, I would much rather accept such correction anytime than some other users unsatisfied with my grammar and not just restricting themselves to the mere correction of minor bits and pieces, but rewriting almost the whole article. I have already observed such things, and sometimes it felt close to presumptuous...That user who did all the rewriting could really be glad SE does not provide a PM option, since otherwise I would have given him a short telling-off :)

Comment: the @syntaxerror 's are to be corrected, tho >:)